# Utopic cannot detect the second HDD in a USB docking station

Tags: 14.10, usb-drive

I have connected a double-HDD USB 3.0 docking station to a freshly installed and updated Ubuntu 14.10 box.  However, Ubuntu is able to detect only the first one of two HDDs plugged into the dock (as seen in `/proc/partitions`).  I have verified the same behavior on another Ubuntu 14.10 box and latest Mint.

At the same time I am able to read SMART data from any of the HDDs by adding `-d usbjmicron,n` option to `smartctl` program.  The same docking station with both HDDs is properly detected on OSX and even when booted with Ubuntu 12.04 rescue CD (kernel 3.2).

Any thoughts on what is going on?

Technical information:

Ubuntu version: `Ubuntu 14.10 Utopic`

````
ws$ uname -a
3.16.0-28-generic #38-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 12 17:37:40 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux```

ws$ lspci
03:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042 SuperSpeed USB Host Controller

ws$ lsusb
Bus 010 Device 002: ID 152d:0539 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. JMS539 SuperSpeed SATA II 3.0G Bridge

ws$ smartctl -d usbjmicron,0 --all /dev/sdi
Model Family:     Toshiba 3.5" HDD DT01ACA...
Device Model:     TOSHIBA DT01ACA300
Firmware Version: MX6OABB0
User Capacity:    3,000,592,982,016 bytes [3.00 TB]
...
````

relevant messages from `dmesg`:

```
usb 10-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
usb 10-1: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=0539
usb 10-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=11, SerialNumber=3
usb 10-1: Product: USB to ATA/ATAPI bridge
usb 10-1: Manufacturer: JMicron
usb 10-1: SerialNumber: 00A123456789
usb-storage 10-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
scsi15 : usb-storage 10-1:1.0
scsi 15:0:0:0: Direct-Access     JMicron                   0000 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
sd 15:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg10 type 0
sd 15:0:0:0: [sdi] 732566646 4096-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
sd 15:0:0:0: [sdi] Write Protect is off
sd 15:0:0:0: [sdi] Mode Sense: 28 00 00 00
sd 15:0:0:0: [sdi] No Caching mode page found
sd 15:0:0:0: [sdi] Assuming drive cache: write through
sd 15:0:0:0: [sdi] 732566646 4096-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
sdi: unknown partition table
sd 15:0:0:0: [sdi] 732566646 4096-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
sd 15:0:0:0: [sdi] Attached SCSI disk
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to force the kernel to rescan SCSI bus and look for a specific LUN on the specific SCSI host.  The command in my case was:

```
rescan-scsi-bus --luns=1 --hosts=15
```

After that the second had drive appeared in `/proc/partitions` and I was able to mount it.

To find the id of the SCSI host (in `--hosts=15`) on your system use the command `lsscsi`.